# How can I change the text of a <span> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a toggle button that I'm adding to an iFrame:

```
<script>
    $('#list div').each(function(){
        $(this).append('<span class="togglebutton">Maximize</span>');   
    });

    $("span.togglebutton").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("li").children("div").toggleClass("maximized");
    });
</script>
```

How can I change the toggle between the text Maximize/Minimize when the toggleClass is maximized?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "toggle button." That's just a `<span>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("span.togglebutton").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);  // cache jquerized 'this'
    $this.closest("li").children("div").toggleClass("maximized");

    var currentText = $this.text();

    // if the text is currently "Maximize"
    if (currentText === "Maximize") {
        // change it to new value
        $this.text("New Text");
    }
    else {
        // change it back to "Maximize"
        $this.text("Maximize");
    }
});
```

Comment: This changes the text, but now when I click on the span again, it remains "new text" at this point I want it to revert back to "maximize"

Comment: add a simple conditional to check the current value of the text... I'll update to demonstrate

Comment: That would be great, I tried the function in the answer above, with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are looking for some function like `toogleClass()` to do that job for you, you are out of luck. AFAIK, you have to do it manually.

Do something like this

```
function toggleText() {
    var curText = $("span.togglebutton").text();
    var newText;
    if(curText=="Maximize") { newText = "Minimize"; }
    else { newText = "Maximize"; }
    $("span.togglebutton").text(newText);
}
```

Now you can call it happily where you want to toggle it. Like

```
    $("span.togglebutton").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("li").children("div").toggleClass("maximized");
        toggleText();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Unfortunately, when I add the function inside of my script tag, it doesn't change the text between Maximize and Minimize. When I do a console log, seems like Maximize is getting called twice..

Comment: Try using Id Selector instead of Class selector. It will work surely.

Comment: I think the culprit is == and === in the curText comparison :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).text('New Text');
```

OR

```
$(this).val('New Text');
```

Determine state.

```
if ($this.text() == 'Maximized') {
    $(this).text('Minimized');
} else {
    $(this).text('Maximized');
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is good, except how can I determine the state of the span? Essentially when I click on the span i want it to say "Maximize" and then when I click on it again I want it to say "Minimize"

Comment: View edit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559070/how-can-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element/7559078#7559078

Comment: @jondavidjohn I understand that, he didn't specify what he was changing.

Comment: Yes but his text says "`toggle button`".

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span.togglebutton").toggle(function() {
    $(this).closest("li").children("div").addClass("maximized")
    $(this).text("Maximized Text");
},function(){
    $(this).closest("li").children("div").removeClass("maximized")
    $(this).text("Minimized Text");
});
```